# AngularFire2 - Trying to combine multiple observables into one giant "Project" object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I've got a Firebase database where I'm aggregating a bunch of project data with check requests. I've created this function to do all of this for me, but the resulting data is not what I'm expecting.

First, I grab a user that has a list of projects associated with them:

`/users`

```
{
      "current_account_id" : "<accountID>",
      "projects" : {
        "<projectID>" : true
      }
}
```

Then for each project, I get the requests associated with that project:

`/projects`

```
{
    "<accountID>" : {
      "<projectID>" : {
        "name" : "Stevie's Fun Project",
        "requests" : {
          "<requestID>" : true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then once I get the requests, I check if the requests are associated with a user as I store them in a `user_check_requests` tree:

```
{
    "<projectID>" : {
      "<userID>" : {
        "<requestID>" : {
          "last_updated" : "2017-03-20T14:32:45.756Z",
          "status" : "pending",
          "timestamp" : -1490020365756
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I take the associated requests (ones that aren't null) and I go and grab the actual request from a different tree:

`/check_requests`

```
{
   "<requestID>": {
     "vendor_id": "<vendorID1>"
     ... 
   }
}
```

Basically, I need a list of objects that come back like this, assuming all of the other data

```
  // this would be the array of project objects (of what at least one would look like)
[
    {
       name: "Project Fun",
       requests: [
         request1: {
            ...,
            "status": "pending",
            "last_updated" : "2017-03-20T14:32:45.756Z"
         }
       ]
    }
]
```

but instead of I'm actually just getting something that looks like this:

```
// It looks to be an array of arrays of requests, instead of an object that represents a project that contains requests in a flattened array:



   [
       [
         {
           {
              ... <only data from the `/check_requests` tree>
           }
         }
       ]
    ]
```

Here is my ridiculous function that's trying to do all this:

```
getAccountProjects() {

    return this._users.getCurrentUser()
        .switchMap((user) => {
          let accountId = user.current_account_id;
          let projectsArr = [];
          if(user.projects) {

            let projectKeys = Object.keys(user.projects);

            return Observable.combineLatest(
              projectKeys.map(projectKey => {
                return this._af.database.object(`/projects/${accountId}/${projectKey}`).switchMap(project => {
                  let requests = project.requests;

                  if(requests) {
                    let requestKeys = Object.keys(requests);
                    // Check if a user is associated with this request
                    return Observable.combineLatest(
                      requestKeys.map(requestKey => {
                        return this._af.database.object(`/user_check_requests/${project.$key}/${user.$key}/${requestKey}`)
                        .switchMap(userRequest => {
                          if(userRequest.value !== null) {
                            return this._af.database.object(`/check_requests/${userRequest.$key}`)
                          }
                        })
                      }),
                      (...requests) => {
                        console.log('requests', requests);
                        return requests;
                      }
                    )
                  } else {
                    return Observable.of([]);
                  }
                })

              }),
              (...projects) => {
                console.log('projects', projects);
                return projects;
              }
            )

          } else {
            return Observable.of([]);
          }
    });
  }
```

I feel I'm starting to understand how to work with Observables, but this is the most complex "query" I've tried to build, yet. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will be helpful is for you to outline what your requests look like and what shape the corresponding responses take.  Then you can indicate which requests depend on data from which responses. Then it's easier to direct you

Comment: hey there @snorkpete, I do appreciate your comment, it makes sense. I've gone ahead and added all of the object trees that I work with from Firebase and the expected result I hope to achieve. Does all of this help you help me? :)